# SSRS Report Parameters grayed out after postback

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer

We have a website that uses Microsofts Report Viewer control (version 12).  The server is SQL-Server 2012.  Up until a week ago it worked fine.  We have a report that when it opens asks for a start date from a list.  **This works fine** and causes a postback that populates the end date list.  HOWEVER, when the form comes back now both the start and end dates are grayed out.

LoadAsync is false.
KeepAlive is true.
Tried with cookies turned on and off.
Tried using Report Viewer version 11 instead.
Checked the web.config for problems.

Any ideas?
Here's what the web.config file looks like (set up for report viewer version 11)

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpCookies requireSSL="false"/>
    <sessionState timeout="20" mode="InProc" cookieless="false" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the aspx report page that contained the report viewer control has a script that fired on postback and that script reference a missing file.